# How to conditionally replace a column value with another column value?

Tags: r

I am trying to replace values in the column events with values from the column descriptions if events = strikeout. I am working with a large dataset, so this is just a snippet of the observations I have.

```
data <- data.frame("events" = c("strikeout", 
"swinging_strike", "ball", "called_strike", 
"hit_into_play", "strikeout"),
                  "description" = 
c("swinging_strike", "swinging_strike", 
"ball", "called_strike", "double_play", 
"called_strike"))
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` from tidyverse to achieve this. All you need is the `mutate` function to manipulate the `events` column using `if_else` from dplyr as well. In the code below, I'm saying, if events is "strikeout", replace with the corresponding value in "description":

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  "events" = c(
    "strikeout",
    "swinging_strike", "ball", "called_strike",
    "hit_into_play", "strikeout"
  ),
  "description" =
    c(
      "swinging_strike", "swinging_strike",
      "ball", "called_strike", "double_play",
      "called_strike"
    )
)

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(events = if_else(events == "strikeout", description, events))
```

If you don't want to take on any dependencies, you can use base R as follows:

```
data$events[which(data$events == "strikeout")] <- data$description[which(data$events == "strikeout")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
      mutate(events = case_when(
        events == 'strikeout' ~ description,
        TRUE ~ events
      ))
```

case_when() can also be used if you have multiple conditions.